# I am trying to display the amount of time in minutes since an account was created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for authentication in rails. I ran something similar in rails console and it displayed the correct number.

Here is what I ran in console:

```
Coles-MacBook-Pro-2:rq coleschiffer$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.0)
2.1.1 :001 > (Time.now - User.first.created_at.round)/60
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => 1004.61901355 
2.1.1 :002 >
```

Then I used the same class to display the live time difference here:

```
<% Time.now - (user_created_at)/60.round %>
```

But, errors keep popping up

```
undefined local variable or method `user_created_at' for #<#<Class:0x007fa66bfd0660>:0x007fa67186cc60>.
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: where do you define `user_created_at` ?

Comment: I think it is defined by devise.

Comment: well apparently it's running in the wrong context, or undefined, I'd move the method to the user model and apply it on current_user, would that work for u ?

Comment: I will try it out, I think it will work thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd move the method to the model, like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def minutes_since_created
    ((Time.now - created_at) / 60).round
  end
end
```

Then in the view

```
<%= current_user.minutes_since_created %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% Time.now - (@current_user.created_at)/60.round %>
```

Why do you not try [time ago in words](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words)

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(@current_user.created_at) %> 
# if @user is where you keep your user
# will produce '3 minutes' for example
```